# How can I recognize two tokens with no spaces between in a regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match two tokens in a String for example I want to recognize (x) like specialCharacter:( , variable: x, specialCharacter: ).

But my Regex only identifies the first token in the string: specialCharacter:(x)

Here are my Regex:

```
SpecialCharacters("[{|}|(|)|@|&|'|/||`|~|?|:|;]\\s?"),
Variables("\\w")
```

And here is my Java code:

```
package lexer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Lexer{


final ArrayList<Reservada> rs = new ArrayList<Reservada>(); // atributo de mi clase lexer que contendra un arraylist de instancias de Reservada aqui
//sabre cuantos tipos de tokens tengo.


public ArrayList<Token> lex(String entrada){
    final ArrayList<Token> tokens = new ArrayList<Token>(); //arraylist de tokens
    final StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(entrada); // mi tokenizer que tendra el codigo que se pasa como parametro a entrada

    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){

        String palabra = st.nextToken(); //mi palabra es igual a el siguiente token

        boolean matched = false; //mi bandera de encuentra o relacionado la pongo en falso

        int i=0;   // creo una variable i y le asigno 0 esto lo hago para controlar que no haya dos tokens iguales pero relacionados con dos tipos diferentes

        for(Tipos tokenTipo: Tipos.values()){ // recorro todos mis tipos hasta allar el que corresponda a mi palabra



            Pattern patron = Pattern.compile(tokenTipo.patron);
            Matcher matcher = patron.matcher(palabra);

            if(matcher.find()){ // si se encuentra pues hahcemos el proceso de agregar el tipo al token , el valor y inicializar o aumentar al contador de tipos
                i++;
                System.out.println(palabra);

                if(i<=1) { //condicional para que no se repita el token con diferentes tipos
                    boolean ok=true;
                    Token tk = new Token();


                    tk.setTipo(tokenTipo);
                    tk.setValor(palabra);
                    tokens.add(tk);

                    //checo si mi arraylist esta vacio si no es asi recorro todo para saber cual se repite y agregarle al contador uno mas de ese tipo
                    //pongo mi bandera en false si no existe la palabra reservada pues mi bandera ase queda en true asi que creo una instancia de Reservada y la agrego
                    // a mi arraylist

                    if(rs.isEmpty()){
                        Reservada r = new Reservada(tk.getTipo().toString());
                        rs.add(r);
                    }else{
                        for(Reservada x:rs){

                            if(x.reservada.equals(tk.getTipo().toString())){

                                x.size++;
                                ok=false;
                            }
                        }
                        if(ok==true){
                            Reservada r = new Reservada(tk.getTipo().toString());
                            rs.add(r);
                        }

                    }
                    matched=true;
                    System.out.println(i);

                }
            }
            if(!matched){
                //   throw new RuntimeException("No existe tal token");
            }

        }

    }

    return tokens; //regreso mi arraylist de tokens.
}
}
```

I want to separate the String (x) in three different things. Any idea?

Comment: Check [this approach](https://ideone.com/WwLRdq), multiple matching using `\W+|\w+` regex.

Comment: Does it do what you need?

Comment: I'm going to try these solution today, thank you so much!

Comment: it doesn't work the way I expected to do, I use tokenizer to separate the tokens by a space but I want to separate the tokens if , for example I have something like (x) without space, I tried to use the class Scanner with the useDelimiter method and set  delimiters like "(" but I need to save the delimiter character as well... Here is my GitHub repo to my project, thank you so much https://github.com/JaredJHZ/GuiJared

Comment: Finally I was able to do what I needed by creating a new regex "((?<=[\\(|\\)|\\s+|\\{|\\}|\\+|\\-|\\/|//*])|(?=[\\(|\\)|\\s+|\\{|\\}|\\+|\\-|\\/|//*]))" this one and then used the method use delimiter with that regex, thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem with the creation of a new regex:

```
"((?<=[\\(|\\)|\\s+|\\{|\\}|\\+|\\-|\\/|//*])|(?=[\\(|\\)|\\s+|\\{|\\}|\\+|\\-|\\/|//*]))"
```

and then used the method of Scanner called useDelimiter

```
st.useDelimiter(Delimiters.delimiters.patron);
```